# Reflection on inherited static property

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, reflection, properties

I'm having some trouble getting a static property through reflection in .NET 4.0.

Say for example I have the following classes:

```
class Foo
{
    public static int MyProperty
    {
        get { return 1234; }
    }
}

class Bar : Foo
{

}
```

Now if I call:

```
typeof(Foo).GetProperties();
```

I get the expected list of one property, "MyProperty". If instead I call:

```
typeof(Bar).GetProperties();
```

I get nothing. Unfortunately I'm dealing strictly with values stored as `Type` data types, so I can't directly call `typeof(Foo).GetProperties()`.

Thanks for any help!
godwin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` to get static properties declared in a base class:

```
var props = typeof(Bar).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                      BindingFlags.Static | 
                                      BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var prop = typeof (Bar).GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```

If you need private properties you need to add `BindingFlags.NonPublic` as well. See [BindingFlags Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx)